# Supervised neural network

Tags: neural-network

Wanted to ask the opinion of SO experts about the type of neural network I should use to teach it make yes/no answers on the combination of over fifty parameters. Essentially I have a valuation that may produce up to fifty different warnings or errors that are present in what’s being evaluated. So far I’ve been using mean average with coefficients to produce yes/no threshold, but wanted to learn more about applying it through supervised neural network, which I can feed different results and teach it to give final verdict. Which neural network I can use for such undertaking? There are quite a few there and as I’m entering the field of artificial learning, I wanted to which direction I should start looking to.

**EDIT**

What I'm starting to lean towards is employing some kind of back-propagation to adjust coefficients for each of the rule, where the decision of whether barcode data is correct or not will influence those coefficients. I'm pretty sure this can be achieved using a NN, but not exactly sure which one to use.

Comment: Suppose you use a neural network, what type of input do you have? an image? some kind of array of data? 
If its an array of data, does it have a constant size across all examples?

Comment: @RanElgiser I have an array of flags so to say, but it's not constant - it's length is variable based on the evaluation of the barcode data, which checks it for many different things and may give six different types of validation warnings or errors - header data and structure, body data and structure, and a couple of others. For example, when parsing barcode header it may check that one header element has to be of certain format and length, it triggers an error or warning for that element, and there are many such elements in the header and body.

Comment: So to conclude, you evaluate a barcode, you get an array of flags, something like a [yes, no yes, no, no, ...] then using those flags you want to predict whether the barcode is fine or not?

Comment: That's correct, @RanElgiser